# Is there a way to change the URL endpoint of @RequestMapping based on annotation in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, versioning, request-mapping

I want to change the endpoint of a @RequestMapping in Spring Boot based on specific annotation

For example:

```java
@Version(1)
@GetMapping("/test")
public ResponseEntity test(){
   return new ResponseEntity();
}
```

this should product the endpoint:
/v1/test

I tried extending the RequestMappingHandlerMapping and overriding getMappingForMethod(Method method, Class<?> handlerType) method

```java
@Component
public class VersionedRequestMappingHandlerMapping extends RequestMappingHandlerMapping {
    @Override
    protected RequestMappingInfo getMappingForMethod(Method method, Class<?> handlerType) {
        RequestMappingInfo methodMapping = super.getMappingForMethod(method, handlerType);
        if (methodMapping != null) {
            Version versionAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(handlerType, Version.class);
            if (versionAnnotation != null) {
                String versionPath = "/v" + versionAnnotation.value();
                RequestMappingInfo typeMapping = RequestMappingInfo.paths(versionPath).build();
                return typeMapping.combine(methodMapping);
            }
        }
        return methodMapping;
    }
}
```

but id did not work

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: I would just put the version like this: GetMapping("v1/test") You will need to implement different methods for different versions anyhow.

Comment: Alternatively with path variable: GetMapping("{version}/test")

Comment: @Mar-Z I know but I want to clean up the endpoints and leave the versioning for an annotation